# Unable to load test React application

Tags: react-native, performance, testing, jmeter, load

I am not able to record a React application's URL in [JMeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_JMeter).
Instead of React URLs, it has recorded API URLs in the tool.

How can we get and test React URLs which we can see on the front end?

I tried the Blaze Meter extension, the JMeter built-in recorder and the [Fiddler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiddler_%28software%29) tool.

Comment: Or is there any other tool used by orgnizations to test react application ?

Answer (score 0):

As per [JMeter project main page](https://jmeter.apache.org/):

> **JMeter is not a browser, it works at protocol level**. As far as web-services and remote services are concerned, JMeter looks like a browser (or rather, multiple browsers); however JMeter does not perform all the actions supported by browsers. In particular, JMeter does not execute the Javascript found in HTML pages. Nor does it render the HTML pages as a browser does (it's possible to view the response as HTML etc., but the timings are not included in any samples, and only one sample in one thread is ever displayed at a time).

I don't know what do you mean by "react urls" but JMeter should record the requests you see in the "network" tab of your [browser developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/Tools_and_setup/What_are_browser_developer_tools) when using your application (apart from requests to i.e. [embedded resources](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/web-testing-jmeter) which should not be recorded)

As long as requests recorded by JMeter and the ones from your browser developer tools match it's fine to use JMeter for your application performance testing.

JMeter won't give you page rendering time, JavaScript execution time, [web vitals](https://web.dev/vitals/) and so on, if you need these metrics - consider using a browser automation tool like [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/) (JMeter can be integrated with Selenium via [WebDriver Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverSampler/)) or [Playwright](https://playwright.dev/) or frontend performance testing solutions like [Lighthouse](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/lighthouse/overview/)